# Only outputting one category group with Channel Form

Tags: channel-form

I have 2 categorys assigned to a channel that I want to use with channel form, however I only want to allow the editor to use 1 of these categories when adding a new element via channel form, I've tried the following:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="work" return="work/thanks"}
     <label for="categories">Categories</label>
     <select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        {categories category_group="2"}
           <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
        {/categories}
     </select>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

But this still outputs both categories, I can't seem to find any parameters in the documentation? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#category-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it should have been show_group instead of category_group

```
{categories show_group="2"}
<option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
{/categories}
```